# Set timeout value for ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN in Oracle (DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT not works)

Tags: oracle, timeout, locking, ddl, freeze

## Question

How I can set a timeout value for nonblocking DDL (ALTER TABLE add column) in oracle so that if any DML lock the table for long time (several hours), my DDL can fast-fail instead of waiting for hours. (we expect oracle raise error like ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired to interrupt our DDL)

P.S: DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT is not working (refer 'What I tried' below)

## Background

I'm working on a big oracle database (Oracle Database 19c). There are legacy application every hour will do aggregation job to calculate the data in past hour, like AVG, SUM of the counters. The production has 40 CPUs and 200GB+ memory, normally the aggregation job will run around 30 minutes， but in some case, like due to maintenance break the aggregation jobs are delayed, more data need to be handle in next aggregation job cause the job running for few hours.

Those legacy applications are out of my control. It's not possible to change the aggregation job.

Edition-Based Redefinition is not used.

My work is update database table (due to new counter added). We use ALTER TABLE to add new column to the existing tables. But in some case, the aggregation job lock the table for hours make my script hang there for hours. It make customer unhappy. So I want to make my script fast-fail.

## What I tried

By google a long time, seems [DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT.html#GUID-72D43EF8-F7AF-4011-8D64-73ABC4FB2154) is the simplest solution.

However, based on the test, we notice that DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT is not works in our case. By a long time google again, we found Oracle document [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/sql-processing-for-application-developers.html#GUID-42F52650-84EC-4D7C-B5A8-FBEFE73366C2) clearly mentioned:

> The DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT parameter affects blocking DDL statements (but not nonblocking DDL statements)

ALTER TABLE add column is exactly 'nonblocking DDL' as listed in [List of Nonblocking DDLs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Automatic-and-Manual-Locking-Mechanisms-During-SQL-Operations.html#GUID-1B08DE66-5ED8-4BEF-893B-B887E3A82D50)

## Expectation

When a DML lock the table for 1 hours, like `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE FOR UPDATE` and commit after 1 hours. I want my DDL like `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (COL_A number)` can get timeout after 10 minutes instead of wait for 1 hour.

## Other Solutions

#### 1

There have one solution in my mind that we can first issue a `lock table MY_TABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE wait 600` to get the lock fist. But before we go with this solution, I want to seek is there any simple solution just like `DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT` to set only one parameter.

#### 2

Based on oracle doc, enable `Supplemental Logging` able to downgrade the nonblocking DDL to blocking way. But Supplemental Logging is DB level configuration. I do not have the permission to do such change.

Comment: hi. what about using two scheduler jobs maybe? 

job 1 starts job 2 and then sleeps 10 minutes. when it wakes up, it ends job 2 if it is still running.

job 2 does the alter table.

just an idea. edit: actually the logic of job 1 could go right into your script so you only need job 2 and the script.you can also make it sleep 1 minute 10 times if you want to save time in the cases where it is fast. here is how to force-stop a job from a procedure: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9508881800346771021

Comment: Thanks Peter. Seems yes, it one of possible solution. But for my update I need update hundreds tables every time, based on the provided link, I understand that I need rewrite all the SQL to define it as a job so that later I can STOP it.  Seem it more complex than run a LOCK TABLE statement before every SQL.